# How to get a query string in a windows phone 8.1 app?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Sorry to ask such a basic question, but I've spent the last 30mins on google and found nothing (very likely my poor search engine skills!)

I'm upgrading (well, moving code) from a windows phone 8 app to a universal app (the windows store code is largely absent at the moment, I'm currently concentrating on porting over the windows phone stuff).

Previously I was using

```
NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue
```

But with 8.1 this doesn't work and I can't for the life of me find out how to get the querystring.

Any help would be very gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can send a parameter the way Vyas_27 written, but make it looks like

```
//id - first parameter
//value - second parameter
Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage), "id&value");
```

To get parameters

```
string[] parameters = ((string)e.Parameter).Split(new char[] {'&'});
string id = parameters[0];
string value = parameters[1];
```